# Kafka Streams - Cannot get state store because the stream thread is STARTING, not RUNNING

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Trying to create a state store using the Kafka Streams API. KafkaStreams object never reaches a RUNNING state, remains in STARTING state indefinitely.

```java
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        streams = new KafkaStreams(
                buildTopology(),
                buildConfig()
        );

        System.out.println("Starting streams");

        streams.cleanUp();

        streams.start();

        boolean waiting = true;
        while (waiting) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                store = streams.store(STORE_NAME, QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore());
                waiting  = false;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }

        // Add shutdown hook to respond to SIGTERM and gracefully close Kafka Streams
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                streams.close();
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                // ignored
            }
        }));
    }
```

Output

```sh
Starting streams
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.InvalidStateStoreException: Cannot get state store realtime-store because the stream thread is STARTING, not RUNNING
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.InvalidStateStoreException: Cannot get state store realtime-store because the stream thread is STARTING, not RUNNING
```

etc

Comment: I think you're blocking the main thread

Comment: I don't think so. Even if I move the while loop to another thread, the result is the same.

Comment: Why do you call `cleanup()`? This wipes out local state and state needs to be rebuild from scratch? I would turn on logging to monitor the startup progress.